# Change tint color of NavBar in AppDelegate when PushNotif is received

Tags: swift, push-notification

I try to change the tint color of my navigationBar if I receive a push notification, but it doesn't work.

The way I thought it would work is:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
self.setupUserInterface(color: UIColor(red: 208.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 27.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
}

func setupUserInterface(color color: UIColor) {
    // Navigation Bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color

    if let barFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 17.0) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Status Bar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
}
```

I know that the PushNotif is received correctly and everything else works fine, but the UI doesn't respond to this. Do I need to change it in a different way?

Comment: Your function is getting called?

Comment: yes, but nothing changes

Comment: Changing UIAppearance will only change new navBar's that are made, not the instances of NavBar already made. I'm working on an answer right now that involves a UINavigationBar class extension.

Comment: Oh! Thats interesting! I didn't know that! Would be great to learn more

Comment: Yeah at run time you have to grab the actual instance of the navBar and change it's background color directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but only on newly instantiated `UINavigationController` (which you don't normally re-instantiate). This means you manually have to update the already existing navigation controller.

There are several ways to implement this, some easier, some safer, but here is a really simple example using KVO Notifications:

```
func setupUserInterface(color color: UIColor) {
    // Navigation Bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color

    if let barFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 17.0) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Status Bar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    // Informs the whole app to refresh if they have a navigation controller
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("awesomeNotificationKey", object: color)
}
```

Then register for this notification, either in a subclass of `UINavigationController` or in a `UIViewController` which is in the stack of a navigation controller. This example will be in a `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SomeController.refreshNavigationBar(_:)), name:"awesomeNotificationKey", object: nil);
}

func refreshNavigationBar(notification: NSNotification) {
    let color = notification.object as! UIColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = color
}
```

Just remember to remove the force unwrappings, remove the notification observer and those kind of things before using code like this in production.

Comment: @sesc360 This is a better answer than mine especially if your navigationController is not the rootViewController of your window.

Comment: I wonder if you can create an extension in UINavigationController, override viewDidLoad(), and addObserver(self) there so that every UINavigationController within the app receives the notification? What would your opinion be on that approach @Kumuluzz ?

Comment: It is unfortunately not possible to override the standard lifecycle methods in an extension, but in any case I would prefer to subclass `UINavigationController` to something like `PushResponsiveNavigationController` in which I would override `viewDidLoad`. I prefer this over an extension because of two reasons: It would have better readability of the storyboard/code compared to an extension and it also allows for the possibility to have a `UINavigationController` that does not react to push.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UINavigationBarExtension

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func didGetNotification(color : UIColor) {
        self.barTintColor = color
        //Do any other visual changes to current navBar instance here.
    }
}
//I would keep most stuff in this function if you want new navBar's to have changes.
func setupUserInterface(color color: UIColor) {
    // Navigation Bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color

    if let barFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 17.0) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
    }

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Status Bar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    // Using self.window assuming you are in AppDelegate.swift
    //Grab instance of current navBar and call your function that changes apperance.
    (self.window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController).navigationBar.didGetNotification(color)
}
```

This will work if your navigation Bar is the rootView controller of the window which in a lot of cases it is. If it is not you will have to come up with another way to grab the instance of the navBar but calling the function is the same.

Comment: Just realized you passed in a color to be change you're navBar too. I'll update my answer.